# How to test Angular subscribe function inside a returned Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have a service that returns a Promise, inside of which before it resolves it gets the data from a JSON file using a subscribe.

I want to be able to test the result of this promise depending on the provided parameters I'm giving it, but currently it either times out with the `"Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test"` error or the test passes (incorrectly) because the subscribe part isn't getting hit.

service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


export interface IAppConfig {
  env: {
    name: string;
  };
  features: {
    [key: string]: boolean;
  };
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConfigService {


  static appSettings: IAppConfig;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

load() {
    const jsonFile = displayJsonFile
      ? `../../../../assets/.json1`
      : `../../../../assets/.json2`;

    return new Promise<any>((resolve) =>
      this.http.get(jsonFile).subscribe((res) => {
    appSettings = res
    resolve(res);
    })
    );
  }
}
```

```
  import { TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ConfigService } from './config-service.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('ConfigService', () => {
  let service: AppConfigService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  const mockConfig = {
    env: {
      name: 'json1',
    },
    features: {
      feature1: true,
      feature2: true,
    },
  };

  
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [HttpClientTestingModule] });
    service = TestBed.inject(AppConfigService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  
  it('should load config file when environment is prod', () => {
    service.load().then(res => expect(res).toBe(mockConfig)
    
  });

});
```

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/

Answer (score 0):

The test needed a part of the answer provided by @Chintan Dhokai above and an adjustment to account for the observable:

```
import { TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppConfigService } from './app-config.service';
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController,
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('AppConfigService', () => {
  let service: AppConfigService;
  let httpMock: HttpClient;
  const mockConfig = {
    env: {
      name: 'json1',
    },
    features: {
      feature1: true,
      feature2: true,
    },
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [HttpClientTestingModule] });
    service = TestBed.inject(AppConfigService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it('should load config file', async () => {
    const spyHttp = jest.spyOn(httpMock, 'get');
    spyHttp.mockReturnValue(of(Promise.resolve(mockConfig)));
    const result = await service.load();
    expect(result).toEqual(mockProdConfig);
  });
});
```